# Shouldn't "text-align: center;" applied to an absolutely positioned element, do nothing to its child elements?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'll let you see the code first then tell you what my problem is:

*Tinkerbin: http://tinkerbin.com/x8iGCFsZ*

```
<style>
  div.container{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  div.subContainer{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }

  div.inner{
   position: absolute;
   background-color:yellow;
   width: 150px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="subContainer">
    <div class="inner">bananas for breakfast</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, according to the textbook, `text-align: center;`, when applied to a parent element, only centers its child elements if they have `display: inline;`.

Therefore, and as you'd expect, since a `<div>` has by default display set to block (`display:block;`) the `text-align: center;` applied to the parent `div.subContainer` doesn't do anything to its child `div.inner`.

Everything fine so far. Nothing weird.

My problem arouses when I try using `<span>`, instead of `<div>` on the `.inner` element, and I position it absolutely (`position: absolute;`) — which, as you know force changes the display, from its default inline, to block.

Take a look:

```
<style>
  div.container{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  div.subContainer{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }

  span.inner{
   position: absolute;
   background-color:yellow;
   width: 150px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="subContainer">
    <span class="inner">bananas for breakfast</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What happens is weird. In spite of having the forced display value of block (thanks to the `position: absolute;`) the span is still centered. And even more, the centering is actually weird. It takes the left side of the block and aligns it with the center of the containing element, instead of, as usual, aligning both center.

The behavior is fixed — starts acting like a block — when I manually set the display on the `span.inner` to block.

```css
span.inner{
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   background-color:yellow;
   width: 150px;
}
```

So, what's happening here? Does the absolutely positioning not force change the display to block? Why is the centering weird?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you set it to `position: absolute`, it does become a block, but it gets removed from the flow of content **at the point it would have originally appeared**. Since you are not using `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right`, this is much more noticeable.

**When using a `<div>`**: A division, by default, is block-level and will take up the entire width possible. So it would, by default, start at the left side of the box and expand to the right. Positioning this absolutely would keep it at the top left corner where it *originally* appeared, the only noticeable difference being the width of the box.

[image: result-with-div]

**When using a `<span>`**: A span, by default, is an inline element which is affected by the `text-align` property of it's parent. The text cursor starts at the **center** of the element, and as text is entered, the characters are added and re-centered to adjust to the width of the text. When you remove the span from the flow, it starts at the point where the **text** would have started. The text cursor is at the very center (horizontally) of the element, since now there is no text in the actual parent.

[image: result-with-span]

You've already found the solution: adding `display: block` will force the element to actually be a block-level element. The thing is, just because `position: absolute` "forces" this property, it's not an *actual* property, only a *computed* value for the element. That being said, it only gets applied to the element's position when its explicitly set in its CSS definitions.

Comment: Seriously, that's a fantastic answer: **+1**

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I think I got it. Where can I read more about this stuff? I haven't yet read Eric Meyer's Definitive CSS Guide. Does it cover these details?

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo: I wouldn't know, I've never read CSS guides/books. Most of my knowledge comes from experience and random research I've done while being frustrated in my experiences. The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS) is a good place for general information about properties.

Comment: Man, your answer deserve +2 just for this phrase "at the point it would have originally appeared."

Comment: Consider using PNG instead of JPG for illustrations.